# popupopen event handler runs before popup actualy opens

Tags: leaflet

Consider this code:

```
    L.marker({lat: 30.267222, lon: -97.743056})
        .addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("hello world!")
    .on('popupopen', function(e) { alert('this far'); });
```

When I run it the `alert()` runs before the popup actually appears. Is there a way to make it so that some javascript code runs *after* the popup appears?

I ask because I'm trying to run some javascript *after* the popup appears that'd do stuff to the visible elements. If the popup isn't open when the popupopen event handler runs then that javascript clearly won't work.

Any ideas?

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7qn2dksb/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about using a short delay using `setTimeout`?

```
 L.marker({
        lat: 30.267222,
        lon: -97.743056
      })
      .addTo(mymap)
      .bindPopup("hello world!")
      .on('popupopen', function(e) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert('this far');
        }, 100)
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>



</head>

<body>



  <div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh"></div>
  <script>
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView({
      lat: 30.267222,
      lon: -97.743056
    }, 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(mymap);




    L.marker({
        lat: 30.267222,
        lon: -97.743056
      })
      .addTo(mymap)
      .bindPopup("hello world!")
      .on('popupopen', function(e) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert('this far');
        }, 100)
      });
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```